# Eclipse loses classpath src entries after Gradle IDE `refresh all`

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, classpath

I have an existing Spring web-app that I wish to convert to a gradle project. I downloaded the Gradle IDE plugin and converted to Gradle project. This reset my .classpath and .project files and got rid of my src entries that are neccesarry for my application to run. So no big deal I thought, I would just go in and add them back, which I did. The problem is that when I right click on my project and choose Gradle STS -> refresh all, it resets my .classpath and .project back to how they were without my src entries. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Does Gradle itself have a way of specifying source folders?

Comment: @nitind Just looked into that, it appears that it does.